# Using dynamically added checkbox to delete data from listview populated from database in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, checkbox

Hi I am building an android app that uses checkbox to delete checked data from SQLite database. I write this code to populate data from SQlite database.

```
public class DisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> id;
    private ArrayList<String> firstName;
    private ArrayList<String> lastName;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> position=new ArrayList<Integer>();


    public DisplayAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> id,ArrayList<String> fname, ArrayList<String> lname) {
        this.mContext = c;

        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = fname;
        this.lastName = lname;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return id.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Holder mHolder;
        final int a=pos;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        if (child == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listcell, null);
            mHolder = new Holder();
            mHolder.txt_id = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
            mHolder.txt_fName = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_fName);
            mHolder.txt_lName = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_lName);
            mHolder.checkbox  = (CheckBox) child.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            mHolder.checkbox.setTag(a);
            position.add(a);
            mHolder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                        //Toast.makeText(mContext, ""+a,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            child.setTag(mHolder);

        } else {
            mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }
        mHolder.txt_id.setText(id.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_fName.setText(firstName.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_lName.setText(lastName.get(pos));

        return child;
    }

    public class Holder {
        CheckBox checkbox;
        TextView txt_id;
        TextView txt_fName;
        TextView txt_lName;
    }

}
```

I have a button (Delete) on the listView activity.After checking the checkboxes When a user presses delete button It will delete the data which was cecked from database and show the rest of the data remaining in Database.
This is the activity where I am handling the click.

```
public class DisplayActivity extends Activity {

    private DbHelper mHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;

    private ArrayList<String> userId = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> user_fName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> user_lName = new ArrayList<String>();

    private ListView userList;
    private AlertDialog.Builder build;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_activity);


        userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List);

        mHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        Button delete=(Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if(userId.size()>0){

                        for(int i=0;i<DisplayAdapter.position.size();i++){
                            Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this, ""+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            View getView=userList.findViewWithTag(DisplayAdapter.position.get(i));
                            CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) getView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                            if(checkbox.isChecked()){
                                //Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this, ""+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dataBase.delete(
                                        DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,
                                        DbHelper.KEY_ID + "="
                                                +userId.get(i), null);

                                displayData();
                            }

                        }

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this, "Nothing Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        //add new record
        findViewById(R.id.btnAdd).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AddActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("update", false);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        //click to update data
        userList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AddActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("Fname", user_fName.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("Lname", user_lName.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("ID", userId.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("update", true);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        displayData();
        super.onResume();
    }

    /**
     * displays data from SQLite
     */
    private void displayData() {
        dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
                + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);

        userId.clear();
        user_fName.clear();
        user_lName.clear();
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                userId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ID)));
                user_fName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME)));
                user_lName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME)));

            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        DisplayAdapter disadpt = new DisplayAdapter(DisplayActivity.this,userId, user_fName, user_lName);
        userList.setAdapter(disadpt);
        mCursor.close();

    }



}
```

It only deletes the first checked item from listview and as well databases.But i want to delete all the checked data from database.How do i do that? Details code and explanation would be appreciated. Thank in advance and sorry if i made any mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a approach how you can implement this.

You can keep an `ArrayList` as a member variable and pass it to the constructor of `DisplayAdapter`. Whenever a user clicks your `CheckCox` add the position of the clicked item into your `ArrayList` and whenever user clicks it again just remove it from the `ArrayList`.

Then you can use an `AsyncTask` and in `doInBackground()` you can perform your delete operation from database and also delete data from `ArrayList` as well. Then inside your `onpostExecute()` you can call your `notifyDatasetChanged()` of your adapter.

Comment: Hi.Your procedure matches in my codes. I have added position to arraylist when user clicks on cheeckBox then  I loop through and perform delete operation...But I am facing a problem I cannot handle the uncheck operation.I did this arraylist.remove(position)..Where arraylist the List that records my checkedBox checked position. But when i uncheck checkbox the app crashes..Any solution?

Comment: @MuhidulHassan You need to provide your LogCat for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565762/how-to-show-full-screen-loading-spinner-for-webview-in-android-fragment

Can you please help me with this.?

Answer (score 0):

The approach I use and thus recommend is this:

On your adapter add a checked callback:

```
    List<YOUR_OBJ> checkedObjs;
    onUserCheckBoxCallback callback;
    ...
    public void OnCheckBoxCheckedCallback(onUserCheckBoxCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    //this part goes on bindView
    yourCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        callback.onUserCheckBoxChanged(your_obj.get(pos), isChecked);
        }
    });

if (checkedObjs!= null && checkedObjs.size() > 0)
        yourCheckbox.setChecked(checkedObjs.contains(your_obj));

//this goes inside the adapter class
 public interface onUserCheckBoxCallback {
        void onUserCheckBoxChanged(YOUR_OBJECT_HERE, boolean isChecked);
    }
```

And on your activity you simply do this:
declare your adapter

```
HashSet<YOUR_OBJ> checkedObjs;
...

//this part goes on onCreate()
adapter.OnCheckBoxCheckedCallback(new onUserCheckBoxCallback() {

@Override
public void onUserCheckBoxChanged(your_obj_type your_obj,boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked)
            checkedObjs.add(your_obj);
        else
        checkedObjs.remove(your_obj);
            }
        });
```

Just iterate trough this list deleting all the objects !

Hope it helps!

Comment: Btw, this is the most "complete" way to do this, if you don't want to hold a reference of the entire object, instead of using a OBJECT list you can just use a List<long> holding the object id's to be deleted!

Comment: Thanks for replaying. Actually I am new to android development. Can you do me a favour.? Can you paste full working code.I am getting all the things you said.

Comment: Which parts are you struggling with ? You just need to simply add this parts into your code and change your_obj to your actual objects !

Comment: Where to add the first block of code? In the getview method?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that ! Gonna edit my code, 1 sec !