# How to show full screen loading spinner for webview in android Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I am developing an app that has a fragment to show website on the webview. For slow connection it takes times to load the website and the app gets blank for few seconds so I want to show a full screen loading spinner in my fragment. I have found  source code but I don't know how to implement this in my class that extends fragment.

This is my fragment where I want to show the full screen loading before showing the website.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        String url="http://www.hotelsearcher.net/";
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args  != null){
            url = args.getString("position");
        }
        WebView webView= (WebView) V.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webViewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webViewSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        adview =(AdView) V.findViewById(R.id.ads);
        Ads.loadAds(adview);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        return V;

    }
}
```

I found this is code : https://gist.github.com/daichan4649/5344979/download#

Can anybody tell me what should I write. to implement the feature.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreateView()` you need to show a `ProgressBar`, since your `webView.loadUrl(url)` takes time to load the internet content on your `WebView`. So you need to register for a call back when your `WebView` is done loading your content. You can listen like this :

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // Cancel your ProgressBar here
    }
});
```

Inside your `onPageFinished()` cancel your `ProgressBar` since your `WebView` has completed loading the content.

**WORKING CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String url = "https://www.google.co.in/";
    ProgressDialog pb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pb = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pb.setTitle("Connecting Station");
        pb.setMessage("Please Wait....");
        pb.setCancelable(false);
        pb.show();
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webViewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webViewSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                pb.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please take a look at this.. 
App crashes ..
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1K1rVUvaSSOrstfDF5K5Db0cstXByG81hRSIT4sy89UA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @MuhidulHassan Kindly post your Logcat along with `ProgressBar` code.

Comment: I have updated the docmunet here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1K1rVUvaSSOrstfDF5K5Db0cstXByG81hRSIT4sy89UA/edit

Please note that I want to show only loading spinner in fullscreen..

Comment: @MuhidulHassan Yes, you are passing your Application's context to your `ProgressDialog` instead pass your Actvitiy's context.

Comment: Ok.can u tell mw how use use the code from github to show full screen loading spinner.?

Comment: @MuhidulHassan I'll post my code which is working. Only difference is that I've not used fragment. Rest all is same.

Comment: @MuhidulHassan Post me your complete fragment code, I'll post you new working code.

Comment: Please take a look here.. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1K1rVUvaSSOrstfDF5K5Db0cstXByG81hRSIT4sy89UA/edit

Comment: Hi Did you find a way to figure the problem? I tried with the code that i shared with you but the problem is It shows loading spinner for sometime not for always.. It stays only less than One second but still screen goes blank.Any suggestion?